# Normal random vector and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)'\in N(\mu,\varLambda)$, where

$$\mu=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\ \ \ \ \ \ \varLambda=\begin{pmatrix} a&a&a\\a&b&b\\a&b&c \end{pmatrix}, \ \ c>b>a>0.$$

How do I find the conditional probability distribution of $X_2$ given $X_3=z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_{X_1, X_2, X_3} (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ represent the joint probability distribution of $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$; essentially, $f_{X_1, X_2, X_3}\sim N(\mu, \varLambda )$ and $f_{X_1, X_2, X_3} (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is the value of $N(\mu, \varLambda)$ at $(X_1, X_2, X_3 ) = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Then

$$f_{X_2 | X_3}(X_2 = x | X_3 = z) = \frac{ \int \limits_{t = -\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X_1, X_2, X_3} (t, x, z) dt}{ \int \limits_{h = -\infty}^{+\infty} \int \limits_{g = -\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X_1, X_2, X_3} (h, g, z) \, dh  \, dg } $$

Comment: Is it valid to say the joint distribution is $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) \sim N(\mu, \varLambda)$ even though we do NOT know whether $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent? Is that because of the fact we have a normally distributed random vector? Are all normally distributed random vectors normally distributed even if the random variables are dependent?

Comment: The above answer is valid and deals with a general case. I am not assuming $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent. Even if they were independent, $\varLambda$ would be a diagonal matrix and the above answer would remain unchanged.

Comment: Which formula is this? I found the following on the wikipedia page for "conditional probability distribution": $f_{X_1|X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)}{f_{X_2}(x_2)}$. Where do the integral signs come from?

Comment: The formula you wrote is exactly the formula I am using. For any joint distribution $f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2)$, we have $f_{X_1}(x_1) = \int_{t = -\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, t)$. The marginal pdf is always obtained from the joint by integrating out over the other random variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution

Comment: @ Okey, superb. I see now that you integrate to "get rid of $X_1$" so that only $f_{X_2,X_3}(x_2,x_3)$ is left (in the numerator). And integrate to "get rid of $X_1$ and $X_2$" so that only $f_{X_3}(x_3)$ is left (in the denominator).